# Using Sikuli and Webdriver - findImageElement fails image detection beyond a certain size

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, sikuli

I am attempting to use Sikuli + WebDriver to detect and verify images (i.e., dashboards) within a website following the example provided at https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver .

With some tweaks to the class that runs SikuliFirefoxDriver (mainly overriding target.setMinScore to 0.97 so that I am matching expected results more precisely), this is working. However, when the sample images I feed to findImageElement go over a certain size, no match is found in the specified timeframe (i.e., from 10 to 180 seconds).

What is more puzzling is that the performance does not degrade gracefully prior to not getting a match. In my "black box" tests, a complicated image of 865x339 matches in less than a second, but another image of 865x348 (just 9 pixels more in height) fails to match, even when I set the default wait timeout (i.e., DEFAULT_WAIT_TIMEOUT_MSECS) to a very large value (i.e., 180 seconds). It's almost as if above a certain threshold the matching function goes into an infinite loop.

Is there something simple that I am missing (i.e., a switch to increase a buffer size) that can prevent this from happening, or has anyone else had this experience?  Thanks.